# Como enviar un alert(" ") desde asp.net, enviando una cadena + una variable

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

De que forma deberia enviar un mensaje tipo alert, desde un formulario asp.net.

Actualmente usaba esto:

```
            if (user._contraseña.Equals(claveI))
            {

                ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('Bienvenido: ');", true);

            }
            else
            {
                ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('Clave incorrecta');", true);
                txtContraseña.Text = "";
            }
```

pero esto me permite solo enviar una cadena, si yo deseo agregar una variable extra, no envia ningun alert.

```
                if (user._contraseña.Equals(claveI))
                {
                String nombre = user.nombreCompleto();
                    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('Bienvenido: ');"+nombre, true);

                }
                else
                {
                    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('Clave incorrecta');", true);
                    txtContraseña.Text = "";
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No estas uniendo el nombre al mensaje, usa algo como esto:

```
string script = string.Format("alert('Bienvenido:{0}');", nombre);
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", script, true);
```

alli veras que en la posicion {0} se agregara el nombre